# Cannot build or run my .NET application in JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm trying out JetBrains Rider on Ubuntu 20.04.1, and I just downloaded a .NET application from my OneDrive to my Linux machine. When I open JetBrains Rider and try to run or build my app the following error appears:

```
Done building project "InterviewTest.csproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

/usr/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2101,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Entity". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
CSC : error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.42
```

I previously tried removing the following 2 packages:

- Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform
- Microsoft.Net.Compilers

as suggested in this question: [CSC: error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639999/csc-error-cs0041-unexpected-error-writing-debug-information-operation-is-n)

But the highlighted solution didn't seem work for me.

UPDATE: I just realized that this project may not be a .NET Standard application. The app seems to work fine on Windows, but according to the JetBrains website, I shouldn't have a problem running this app on Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSC: error CS0041: Unexpected error writing debug information -- 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639999/csc-error-cs0041-unexpected-error-writing-debug-information-operation-is-n)

Comment: Nope that did not solve my issue, I tried the potential solution but I get the same result. I am also using Ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: You are working on a strange project. `System.Web.Entity` is considered Windows only and exclusive to .NET Framework. A .NET Standard project shouldn't use it as reference.

Answer (score 1):

As Lex mentioned, the package `System.Web.Entity` is not a .NET Standard compliant package. If you want to run it you'll have to try run it against Mono by going to `Rider` > `Preferences` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Toolset and Build` > `Use MSBuild version` and select the Mono runtime.